# Merge of css and html code in Angular v16

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular-cli, npm-install

Does anyone know why when I create a new Angular 16 project, I integrate the css styles in the same html template of my component?

Html file:

<style>

</style>

<div>

</div>

Thanks!

Comandos CLI:
npm install @angular/cli
ng new my-app
option: scss styles
npm install

Comment: Can you rephrase your question, It's not quite understandable.

Comment: @Nerm, take a look to [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-overview). You can add the styles: in the component using styles or styleUrls if only want affect to the component, in a styles.css that you indicate in angular.json. Angular works merging all the .css in an unique .css that is loaded in the index.html